# Ansible: How to get rid of teal "included: " statement when you run a Task?

Tags: variables, include, ansible, hide

I am trying to hide this teal `include:`  statement from my Ansible playbook runs. It seems like every time there is an `Mode Script` with an included variable, this teal statement shows up. Any help on being able to hide this would be very much appreciated. Thank you so much!

[Photo: Include statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVE5w.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines are printed by `v2_playbook_on_include` method of callback plugin.

This is how it looks for default stdout plugin:

```
def v2_playbook_on_include(self, included_file):
    msg = 'included: %s for %s' % (included_file._filename, ", ".join([h.name for h in included_file._hosts]))
    self._display.display(msg, color=C.COLOR_SKIP)
```

If you need to omit this, either use less "talkative" stdout callback plugin (e.g. `actionable`), or write your own stdout plugin with required functions.

Simple way to test other callbacks:

```
$ ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=actionable ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! That did the trick. No more teal lines!

Comment: Actionable callback plugin have been removed [Ansible Doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/callback/actionable.html)

Answer (score 1):

I opted for a very simple solution, but it works:

```
ansible-playbook main.yml | grep -v --line-buffered '^included:'
```

Since i use gitlab-ci to run the playbook, i can easily include the `grep` part in each run.